# MYSQL If else query statement

Tags: mysql, vb.net

There is something wrong with my query. Kindly help me please.

```
IF (invoicesearch.CLIENTSNAME <> '' AND invoicesearch.FROM <> '' AND invoicesearch.TO <> '' AND invoicesearch.MIN <> '' AND invoicesearch.MAX <> '' AND invoicesearch.STATUS <> '') then 

SELECT invoicetable.INVOICENUMBER, invoicetable.INVOICEDATE, invoicetable.DUEDATE, invoicetable.CLIENTSNAME, invoicetable.TOTAL,  invoicetable.`STATUS`, Sum(replace(invoicetable.TOTAL,',','')) 
FROM invoicetable , invoicesearch 
WHERE INVOICETABLE.CLIENTSNAME = invoicesearch.clientname 
AND invoicetable.FROM =  invoicesearch.FROM 
AND INVOICETABLE.TO = invoicesearch.TO 
AND MIN(replace(invoicetable.TOTAL,',','')) = invoicesearch.MIN 
AND MAX(replace(invoicetable.TOTAL,',','')) = invoicesearch.MAX 
AND invoicetable.STATUS = invoicesearch.status 
GROUP BY invoicetable.INVOICENUMBER, invoicetable.INVOICEDATE, invoicetable.DUEDATE, invoicetable.CLIENTSNAME, invoicetable.TOTAL,  invoicetable.`STATUS`
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].Debug your code and if it returns any exception then come back here with that

Comment: try to show us the error. why u say that are something wrong?

Comment: with only the select is impossible to know what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

For those condition you specified with `IF`, simply add them in your `WHERE` clause. Feel free to try this query instead:

```
SELECT 
    invoicetable.INVOICENUMBER, 
    invoicetable.INVOICEDATE, 
    invoicetable.DUEDATE, 
    invoicetable.CLIENTSNAME, 
    invoicetable.TOTAL,  
    invoicetable.`STATUS`, 
    Sum(replace(invoicetable.TOTAL, ',' ,''))

FROM 
    invoicetable, 
    invoicesearch

WHERE 
    INVOICETABLE.CLIENTSNAME = invoicesearch.clientname 
    AND invoicetable.FROM =  invoicesearch.FROM 
    AND INVOICETABLE.TO = invoicesearch.TO 
    AND MIN(replace(invoicetable.TOTAL,',','')) = invoicesearch.MIN 
    AND MAX(replace(invoicetable.TOTAL,',','')) = invoicesearch.MAX 
    AND invoicetable.STATUS = invoicesearch.status 
    AND invoicesearch.CLIENTSNAME <> '' 
    AND invoicesearch.FROM <> '' 
    AND invoicesearch.TO <> '' 
    AND invoicesearch.MIN <> '' 
    AND invoicesearch.MAX <> '' 
    AND invoicesearch.STATUS <> ''

GROUP BY 
    invoicetable.INVOICENUMBER, 
    invoicetable.INVOICEDATE, 
    invoicetable.DUEDATE, 
    invoicetable.CLIENTSNAME, 
    invoicetable.TOTAL,  
    invoicetable.`STATUS`;
```

Comment: i want to come up with a condition that filters the invoicetable based on the data inputed in invoicesearch table